# How to listen new port Ubuntu Server from command line?

Tags: networking, server

I want to listen new port on Ubuntu Server.

I am in root access.

```
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
```

Returns :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1270            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29130         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I want to run my .js file on port 3000. So i have fired command :

```
nc -l 3000
```

But then no output.

I am new to Ubuntu, Anyone can help me with it?

EDIT :

I want to listen new port 3000 same as following port :

```
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: run `nc -l 3000 &`

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    but  it should have :::*

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Server itself will not listen to any port. The application services installed and ran at the server listen to ports. For example, by default:

- *sshd* listen at 22,
- *apache2*/*nginx* listen at 80 and 443, etc.

If you want to get the names of the services that listen at the ports on your system,  use `netstat` by root via `sudo` in this way:

```bsh
$ sudo netstat -pna | grep "LISTEN " | grep '\<tcp\>'    
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:6951      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   8976/aria2c         
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:3306    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1589/mysqld         
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:6379    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   32285/redis-server  
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:11211   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1279/memcached      
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:8142    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1482/nodejs         
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:6800    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   8976/aria2c         
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:81      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   3286/docker-proxy   
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.53:53     0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1218/systemd-resolv 
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:4822    0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1445/guacd          
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:80        0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   77768/apache2
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:22        0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1339/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:25        0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   2805/master
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:443       0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   77768/apache2
```

note:

- `127.0.0.1` means the loopback interface (localhost),
- `0.0.0.0`   means all available interfaces (localhost, network adapters, etc.),
- some services could listen at certain interfaces, i.e. `192.168.1.100` or it could be some IPv6 address.

If there is a firewall and you want to access your services outside you need to allow input/output traffic to the ports they listen.

---

By using `nc -l 3000` the command `nc` itself will start to listen at port 3000. IMO, this option is designed for test purposes, i.e. you are setup firewall or so.

Let's say in a terminal you've ran:

```bsh
$ nc -l 3000
```

Then in another terminal you can test does something listen to port 3000 by:

```bsh
$ nc -vz 0.0.0.0 3000
Connection to 0.0.0.0 3000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

And that's it.

---

As conclusion:

Your must design your service (program, script, command) to listen at the desired port 3000 and when this port is not used by some other service, when you start your service it will start to listen to the port.

---

In other hand if you need something to listen constantly at `:::3000` in order to do your tests, the most easiest way, in my opinion, is to create systemd unit. For this purpose:

- Create `/etc/systemd/system/listen-3000.service`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/listen-3000.service
  ```
- As content of `/etc/systemd/system/listen-3000.service` place:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Permanent listen at :::3000
  After=network-online.target

  [Service]
  User=root
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/nc -l6 3000
  ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -s KILL nc
  Restart=always
  RestartSec=1

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Enable and start the `listen-3000.service`:

  ```
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
  sudo systemctl enable listen-3000.service 
  sudo systemctl start listen-3000.service 
  sudo systemctl status listen-3000.service
  ```
- Disable and stop the `listen-3000.service`:

  ```
  sudo systemctl stop listen-3000.service 
  sudo systemctl disable listen-3000.service
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command `nc -l 3000` `nc` will run in foreground and you won't be able to do anything else without stopping `nc`

so you must run `nc` as background task:

`nc -l 3000 &`

Comment: now it showing in listening list but not able to listern. Node throws error Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

Comment: run `killall node` and try again

Comment: not working. Same error. I think it is becasuse` tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN `

Comment: What is output of `ps -ax | grep node`

Comment: 12559 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto node

Comment: try using `nc -lk 3000 &` so it keeps listening after one connection is finished.