# Confusion about nc -l and nc -lp

Tags: command-line, netcat

In the manpage for `nc -l`, it says:

```
It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options.
```

But most examples I see online using this command use `nc -lp [port]`.

Can you use `-p` with `-l` in `nc`? And with just `nc -l [port]`, is that the correct usage of it because when I connect to it on another terminal with `nc [ip address] [port]`, it works. Also, when I use `nc -lp [port]` and connect to it with `nc [ip address] [port]`, it also works. Is there a difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are two netcat packages. And the options are not the same for the `nc` commands they provide:

[netcat-traditional](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/nc.traditional.1.html) shows this command as one of the main examples:

```
nc -l -p port [-options] [hostname] [port]
```

While [netcat-openbsd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/nc.openbsd.1.html) states:

> ```
>  -l      Listen for an incoming connection rather than initiating a connection to a remote
>          host.  The destination and port to listen on can be specified either as non-optional
>          arguments, or with options -s and -p respectively.  Cannot be used together with -x
>          or -z.  Additionally, any timeouts specified with the -w option are ignored.
> ```

So yes, both commands do the same, but you might run into examples that do not work with your version of netcat. For example `-e`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the listen mode `-l` you must specify port. For example:

```bsh
nc -l 3000  # Listen at port 3000 to all network interfaces
```

```bsh
nc -l4 3000  # Listen at port 3000 to all IPv4 network interfaces
```

```bsh
nc -l6 3000  # Listen at port 3000 to all IPv6 network interfaces
```

So actually you do not need an additional option like `-p` to instruct the `nc` command at which port to listen. The examples that uses `-lp` option probably are based on an old version of `nc` or the writers didn't read the manual like you :) Also probably when the `-lp` combination is used the `-p` option is just omitted.

In addition, here is how to create a listen service, based on `nc`: [How to listen new port Ubuntu Server from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1252100/566421)